# Client_side_validations gem doesn't seem to work at all, Rails 3.2.13

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems, client-side-validation

I added `client-side-validations` to my `Gemfile` and ran `bundle install`. Then ran `rails g client_side_validations:install`

It created `config/initializers/client_side_validations.rb` (wheres my JS file? the asset pipeline?)

It's supposed to work out've the box but it didn't seem to.

I went to `config/initializers/client_side_validations.rb` and uncommented the following lines from :

```
#ClientSideValidations Initializer


# Uncomment to disable uniqueness validator, possible security issue
# ClientSideValidations::Config.disabled_validators = [:uniqueness]

# Uncomment the following block if you want each input field to have the validation messages attached.
# ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance|
#   unless html_tag =~ /^<label/
#     %{<div class="field_with_errors">#{html_tag}<label for="#{instance.send(:tag_id)}" class="message">#{instance.error_message.first}</label></div>}.html_safe
#   else
#     %{<div class="field_with_errors">#{html_tag}</div>}.html_safe
#  end
# end
```

to:

```
#ClientSideValidations Initializer


    # Uncomment to disable uniqueness validator, possible security issue
    # ClientSideValidations::Config.disabled_validators = [:uniqueness]

    # Uncomment the following block if you want each input field to have the validation messages attached.
     ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance|
       unless html_tag =~ /^<label/
         %{<div class="field_with_errors">#{html_tag}<label for="#{instance.send(:tag_id)}" class="message">#{instance.error_message.first}</label></div>}.html_safe
       else
         %{<div class="field_with_errors">#{html_tag}</div>}.html_safe
       end
     end
```

I decided to run `rails g client_side_validations:copy_assets` and then I required rails.validations (`//= require rails.validations`) in my `application.js` file (before `//= require tree .`).

When I try to tab out of form fields no inline errors are displayed, when I submit a form no errors are displayed either.

I have the following code for my form and model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  validates_presence_of :email
  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
  validates_length_of :password, :minimum => 6
  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates_uniqueness_of :email
end

<h1>Sign Up</h1>

<%= form_for User.new, :validate => true do |f| %>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.submit "Sign Up" %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

I'm hoping the problem is in my configuration or syntax and not with the gem.

Any insight would be fully appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `3-2-stable` on your Gemfile, and run bundle install

```
gem 'client_side_validations', :github => 'bcardarella/client_side_validations', :branch => '3-2-stable'
```

Comment: Gemfile:26: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting $end
...tions`, :github => 'bcardarella/client_side_validations', :b...
...                               ^ (SyntaxError)

Comment: sorry wrong single quote (gem 'client_side_validations`) change to (gem 'client_side_validations') , try again copy it,

Answer (score 0):

I think your settings seem fine. You are missing "error_messages" class in your form. I did same validation in my project. My code is:

```
<%= f.error_messages :header_message => "oops! you missed something",
  :message => "",
  :header_tag => :h3, :class => "background-color:#d24d33; color:#ffffff" %>
```

Put above code with customization in your form.You need to specify where to display your error and how. This all is defined in above code. 
Please let me know if you need further help.

Comment: I tried this and received the following: `undefined method `error_messages' for #ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x0000000476e040>`